# LAN can connect with computer name but not with IP

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, lan, ping

I've got a small office network, about 20 machines, that all use Windows 7, and the problem described in the title.

Computer TM (the troublemaker) wants to talk to Computer FS (a file server), but it will only do so through the name `COMPUTER-FS`.  An IP address won't work.

The facts:

- FS can ping TM with IP
- TM can *not* ping FS with IP
- TM and FS can both ping eachother using names
- All the other machines work as expected

In a possibly related issue, when users open the `Network` explorer, only a couple of the machines are visible.  Sometimes they're all visible, sometimes not.  This problem has been occurring for several weeks; the ping problem just started today.

How can I troubleshoot this and have TM be able to ping FS using an IP?

---

*EDIT* here's the `ipconfig /all` of Troublemaker:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESIGN-22
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B0-48-7A-80-56-47
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4987:891e:d0f7:a96%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.64(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, October 11, 2013 9:46:47 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 12, 2013 9:47:15 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 246433914
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-16-1D-2C-25-B0-48-7A-80-56-47

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{2AA68601-C7D9-4925-A335-99A3E15FED8E}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:18b2:1221:3f57:ffbf(Pref
erred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::18b2:1221:3f57:ffbf%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

...and here's the file server:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER-2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1C-6F-65-D6-BD-3C
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2d82:c4b0:ae53:d345%13(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.63(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, October 11, 2013 7:50:57 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 12, 2013 7:50:56 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 219967333
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-CA-56-F6-54-E6-FC-80-05-33

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.3
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 54-E6-FC-80-05-33
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{867C36AA-E165-4F91-8936-1E681BE486A8}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{49CECF16-EDD7-46A3-A43A-B87B22E248FB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:853:3c96:3f57:ffc0(Prefe
rred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::853:3c96:3f57:ffc0%15(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: is your "Client for MS Networks" and "File and Printer Sharing for MS Networks" checked in your network adapter connection properties? What about the"Computer Browser" service?

Comment: Yep both checked.  I'm using the default properties config on TM, haven't changed anything.

Comment: File Server is what OS? "Network Discovery" is turned on in "Network and Sharing Center" in win7, but Computer Browser service for older computers/servers..... and its a workgroup/domain?

Comment: They're all Windows 7.  All the other computers on the network are working fine, and have been for years.  The troublemaker was working fine for a long time too, before today.  Its user is not malicious or savvy enough to cause any real trouble. "Network Discovery" should be...yep, it's on too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ping by name, are you getting the ipv6 address returned? Vista and above have this enabled by default, so you don't need an ipv4 network set up correctly to connect.

What are the ipv4 settings? Are they in the same network range, with a proper subnet mask?

Comment: Post the output of "ipconfig /all" from both computers

Comment: AHA yes I am getting IPv6! Now I can fix it.  Thanks!  I'll leave open for a bit until I'm sure this works.  Just a minute I'll get the config.

Comment: OMG I'm an idiot. A few months ago I had re-configured the server to not use an IP.  Today I came into work and for some reason I thought it was still using the old IP.  Sorry for wasting your time, and thanks for the hand-holding.  I completely forgot it was leasing DHCP.  Jiminy christmas, too many things on my plate.

Comment: Every time I have a problem like this it's always back to the basics, never as complicated as I expect. `ipconfig`, firewall, network settings, it's all in there.  I'm usually programming something so I expect a headache whenever a fix crops up, but networking is nice and visible.

Comment: Just need to relax and ask a duck

Comment: lol yep Atwood's got a good post on that (of course) http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html